# Can't hide content and show it again correctly using CSS, different classes interfere

Tags: html, css

I can't hide content on lists and show it again correctly as a classes interfere with other classes. If you click one of the 100ml links it moves the content of the other 100 ml which has a different class (picantesemillascien and picante-cien classes).

The HTML code is:

```css
li.picantesemillascien {
  display:none;
}

li.picantesemillastrescientos {
  display:inline-block;
}

.picantesemillas{
width:100%;
}

.picantesemillas a[class="picantesemillascien"]:focus ~ li:not([class="picantesemillascien"]) {
 display:none;
}

.picantesemillas a[class="picantesemillascien"]:focus ~ li[class="picantesemillascien"] {
 display:inline-block;
}

.picantesemillas a[class="picantesemillastrescientos"]:focus ~ li[class="picantesemillastrescientos"] {
 display:inline-block;
}

.card{
  display: inline-block;
}

li.picante-cien {
  display:none;
}

li.picante-trescientos {
  display:inline-block;
}

.picante{
width:100%;
}

.picante a[class="picante-cien"]:focus ~ li:not([class="picante-cien"]) {
 display:none;
}

.picante a[class="picante-cien"]:focus ~ li[class="picante-cien"] {
 display:inline-block;
}

.picante a[class="picante-trescientos"]:focus ~ li[class="picante-trescientos"] {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="picantesemillas">
  <a href="#" class="picantesemillascien">100ml</a>
  <a href="#" class="picantesemillastrescientos">300ml</a>
  <li class="picantesemillascien">
    semillas cien
  </li>
  <li class="picantesemillastrescientos">
    semillas trescientos
  </li>
</div>
<div class="picante">
  <a href="#" class="picante-cien">100ml</a>
  <a href="#" class="picante-trescientos">300ml</a>
  <li class="picante-cien">
    picante cien
  </li>
  <li class="picante-trescientos">
    picante trescientos
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting a little bit confused here. You might want to check out the difference between adjacent sibling and the general sibling combinator.

Comment: your HTML  is invalid for start

Comment: Dhruvi Makvana I already tried changing ~ (adjacent sibling) for + (general sibling) and if you click on a it just doesn't work

Comment: Dippas what do you mean with my HTML is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, welcome to StackOverflow!

Unless there's some reason you cannot use JavaScript, your use case would probably be better served by having it provide the functionality, and manipulating the DOM instead of using CSS show/hide. Generally, the `focus` pseudo-selector is used as an accessibility enhancement.

Following is a quick mockup accomplishing the same functionality. Also, purely for being concise, I stripped out the `<div>` and `<li>` elements, and made the main elements HTML paragraphs, with spans that can be swapped. In addition, all CSS being called (which was a bit challenging to follow) has been removed, since it wasn't necessary when using the JavaScript.

The code could even be more elegant—the following is for simplicity's sake.

```html
<p>
  <a href="#" onclick="selectionA1()">100ml</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="selectionA2()">300ml</a>
    <span id="choice1">semillas cien</span>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="#" onclick="selectionB1()">100ml</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="selectionB2()">300ml</a>
    <span id="choice2">picante cien</span>
</p>

<script>
  function selectionA1() {
    document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "semillas cien";
  }
  function selectionA2() {
    document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "semillas trescientos";
  }
  function selectionB1() {
    document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = "picante cien";
  }
  function selectionB2() {
    document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = "picante trescientos";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Karolus thank you very much, I've been stocked in this problem for a lot of time and didn't want to use Java but I didn´t have any code that fitted my problem since I don't know to program in Java. You have been most helpful I really appreciate it.